# Need to make my transactions list updatable, in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

Need to make my transactions list updatable, in Android Studio.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-a-simple-expense-calculator-app-in-android/

I built this app using the tutorial above and want to be able to edit my transactions list. Here's as far as I have gotten. I have no idea how to proceed from this point on.

I added an update android drawable file, added the drawable file to my transaction row xml, then I added the following ivUpdate files to the end of my transaction adapter. I assume I next would want to copy and past my delete click listener portion of code in my transaction adapter but I don't know what alterations are necessary.

```
// View Holder for a Transaction
public static class TViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tvAmount,tvMessage;
    ImageView ivDelete;
    ImageView ivUpdate;

    public TViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
        tvMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        ivDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);
        ivUpdate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivUpdate);
    }
}
```

}